# Trying to remove older pics from image picker camera storage

Tags: flutter

I have an app which is used for taking pictures and sending them to the server. I use Image Picker -> Camera to take photos and they are stored in the default Image Picker storage.
I wrote a method to check for photos older than *x* days and removing them from the storage. However the path returned from the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` method: `/data/user/0/com.example.buzzbee/app_flutter` is not what it is really on the phone: `Android/data/com.example.buzzbee/files/Pictures`.

Any ideas of what is going on? Where is this additional "app_flutter" coming from - do I need to erase it manually?

Here is the code:

```
      Future<void> clearOldPictures({int daysOld}) async {
        var directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
        debugPrint('APP STORAGE DIRECTORY: $directory');
         var pictureList = Io.Directory("$directory/files/Pictures/").listSync();
        debugPrint(pictureList.toString());
    
        for (var picture in pictureList) {
          var stat = Io.FileStat.statSync(picture.path);
          var createdDate = stat.accessed;
          var daysOld = DateTime.now().difference(createdDate).inDays;
          if (daysOld >= daysOld) {
            picture.delete();
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: For the moment I was forced to detect the correct image path from ImagePicker within the widget that is responsible for taking photos. This path is stored in SharedPreferences and then used in the method above. BTW. the above method works ...